# Size of a Typedef'd 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, typedef, sizeof

Given a typedefined 2-dimensional array:

```
typedef float Matrix3x3[3][3];
```

If I want to get the total number of `float`s in `Matrix3x3` I feel like I should be able to just do:

```
sizeof(Matrix3x3) / sizeof(**Matrix3x3)
```

But obviously I cannot dereference a type. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Note: Many of the answers below do just about the same thing, so I wanted to make sure what it's doing is clear to any reader. `sizeof(Matrix3x3)` returns 36, because that's the number of bytes taken by a single instance (9 floats * 4 bytes per float). You can then divide that by the size of a single element to determine how many elements there are. The answers below mostly differ in how they determine the size of a single element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::remove_all_extents`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_all_extents).

```
sizeof(Matrix3x3) / sizeof(std::remove_all_extents_t<Matrix3x3>)
```

It's a trait that essentially removes all the square brackets from the array type, no matter how many dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you want to divide, not multiply. Second of all, customary way would be

```
auto n_elements = sizeof(Matrix3x3) / sizeof(std::declval<Matrix3x3>()[0][0]);
```

That gives expected value of `9`.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's C++ rather than C, I would write a proper type trait:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
inline constexpr std::size_t total_extent_v = 1;

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
inline constexpr std::size_t total_extent_v<T[N]> = N * total_extent_v<T>;
```

Usage:

```
std::cout << total_extent_v<Matrix3x3> << '\n';
```

---

If this is too much and you want something simpler, I would use a `std::remove_all_extents_t`-based solution as suggested by @StoryTeller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
sizeof(Matrix3x3)/sizeof(float)
```

Comment: I assume OP wants to avoid hardcoding actual type of array element there. Otherwise the question is too trivial.